Lines of force of a conservative field
I am new at the study of electromagnetism and I do not understand why the lines of force of a conservative field (as the electric field in the stationary case) cannot be closed. Is it perhaps because if it were so, then the field and the displacement would be parallel all along the closed line, thus there would exists a closed path such that the work calculated along it would not be zero?
Thanks for any answer!

yes that’s exactly it (once you add in the technical caveat of being a non-constant closed curve).

"thus there would exists a closed path such that the work calculated along it would not be zero?" - Yes.

System - positive charge.
You start with a positive charge somewhere on the closed field line.
You move the charge in a direction opposite to the direction of the field line doing external work against the force on the charge due to the electric field.
Eventually you arrive at the position you started from having done external work on the charge.
If the field was conservative then no external work would have been done when a charge started at a given position and finished at the same position.
